# Understanding shuffle managers in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partitioning, shuffle

Let me help to clarify about **shuffle in depth** and how Spark uses **shuffle managers**. I report some very helpful resources:

https://trongkhoanguyenblog.wordpress.com/

https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/

https://github.com/JerryLead/SparkInternals/blob/master/markdown/english/4-shuffleDetails.md

Reading them, I understood there are different shuffle managers. I want to focus about two of them: `hash manager` and `sort manager`(which is the default manager).

For expose my question, I want to start from a very common transformation:

```
val rdd = reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

This transformation causes **map-side aggregation** and then **shuffle** for bringing all the same keys into the same partition.

My questions are:

- Is Map-Side aggregation implemented using internally a mapPartition transformation and thus aggregating all the same keys using the combiner function or is it implemented with a `AppendOnlyMap` or `ExternalAppendOnlyMap`?
- If `AppendOnlyMap` or `ExternalAppendOnlyMap` maps are used for aggregating, are they used also for **reduce side aggregation** that happens into the  `ResultTask`?
- What exaclty the purpose about these two kind of maps (`AppendOnlyMap` or `ExternalAppendOnlyMap`)?
- Are `AppendOnlyMap` or `ExternalAppendOnlyMap` used from all shuffle managers or just from the sortManager?
- I read that after `AppendOnlyMap` or `ExternalAppendOnlyMap` are full, are **spilled into a file**, how exactly does this steps happen?
- Using the Sort shuffle manager, we use an appendOnlyMap for aggregating and combine partition records, right? Then when execution memory is fill up, we start sorting map, spilling it to disk and then clean up the map, my question is : what is the difference between spill to disk and shuffle write? They consist basically in creating file on local file system, but they are treat differently, Shuffle write records, are not put into the appendOnlyMap.
- Can you **explain in depth** what happen when reduceByKey being executed, explaining me all the steps involved for to accomplish that? Like for example all the steps for map side aggregation, shuffling and so on.

Answer (score 6):

It follows the description of `reduceByKey` step-by-step:

1. `reduceByKey` calls `combineByKeyWithTag`, with identity combiner and identical merge value and create value
2. `combineByKeyWithClassTag` creates an [`Aggregator`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Aggregator.scala#L32) and returns `ShuffledRDD`. Both "map" and "reduce" side aggregations use internal mechanism and don't utilize `mapPartitions`.
3. `Agregator` uses `ExternalAppendOnlyMap` for both [`combineValuesByKey`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Aggregator.scala#L40) ("map side reduction") and [`combineCombinersByKey`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Aggregator.scala#L49) ("reduce side reduction")
4. Both methods use `ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAllMethod`
5. `ExternalAppendOnlyMap` [keeps track of spilled parts](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala#L85) and the current in-memory map (`SizeTrackingAppendOnlyMap`)
6. `insertAll` method updates in-memory map and [checks on insert](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala#L160-L162) if size estimated size of the current map exceeds the threshold. It uses inherited `Spillable.maybeSpill` method. If threshold is exceeded this method calls [`spill` as a side effect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/Spillable.scala#L97), and `insertAll` initializes clean `SizeTrackingAppendOnlyMap`
7. `spill` calls [`spillMemoryIteratorToDisk` which gets `DiskBlockObjectWriter` object](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala#L186) from the block manager.

`insertAll` steps are applied for both map and reduce side aggregations with corresponding `Aggregator` functions with shuffle stage in between.

As of Spark 2.0 there is only sort based manager: [SPARK-14667](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14667)